# Mosaico Left Aligns All Text

Tags: civimail, mosaico

Using Drupal, Civi 7.30, Mosaico 2.0 Beta 3

Whenever we center align text - its shows up as such in Mosaico, but then will left align in html preview and when actually sending email. Also shows up in source as correctly aligned in mosaico, but not when sent.

Any idea why this is?

[Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/issues/237)

Answer (score 3):

If you select your text and put it into a DIV block and then choose the alignment it should be fine. I have found the the paragraph block does not hold the alignment.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have been able to center is by choosing a block that is a section title. I usually have to reduce the font size. I too would love to center something when using the 166 x 90 3 in one block. Have not figured how to get it to hold the centering under each picture.